# Appending text from an array to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Doesn't sound too hard, does it? Well, to me it is. I've done something horribly wrong in my coding I guess, but I can't figure it out.

This script is supposed to pick a quote form an array and paste it into the div #quotes.

```
    var quotes = [
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "4"
];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length());
var newQuote=function() {
   $("#quotes").append("<p>" + quotes[index] + "</p>");
};
```

Answer (score 7):

[`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) is not a function. If you change `.length()` to `.length`, it should work correctly.

<kbd>[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/c3swqnk8/)</kbd>

(Not to be confused with [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/), which *is* a function, but was deprecated in jQuery v1.8)

Comment: I make this mistake all the time, lol. Though it shows that you aren't using any debugging methods if you can't catch this. Use the console on your browser and it should spit out an error like "number is not a function".

Comment: I've just run in to another that I can't seem to fix.

I've got my script http://jsfiddle.net/vrs30m9g/
Which is supposed to place a random quote from the array into #text. This works. Except the function can only be called once, even though it generates a random index every time it is called. Why does it behave this way? How can this be fixed?

Comment: You are using the `.replaceWith` function when you shouldn't be. The `.replaceWith` will remove the `#text` div and put the quote in its place. You should use `.html` instead to replace the inside of the div.